# Regular changes to an htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, audio

I have a site that hosts a monthly podcast and on most pages there is an audio player that plays the latest episode.

I have it set to play latest.mp3 and .ogg and hoped to use an htaccess redirect every time a new episode comes out to redirect it to the correct new audio file.

Problem is, certainly in Firefox anyway, it seems as if the browser is caching the redirect info.
Is there a better way of doing this?

I guess I could duplicate the audio files and rename them latest.mp3 and .ogg but I assume that I'd have the same problem if the browser caches the audio file.

Any clues?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do here. First is to not use a `301` redirect in your .htaccess file. Most browsers are known to cache it aggressively because the spec says `301` is a permanent redirect. Use `[R]` that does a `302` redirect which is temporary in nature.

If you are already doing that and yet some browsers are not behaving as expected, you can append a timestamp at the end of your audio link. For example, in `PHP` it would look like

```
<a href="blog/audio/latest.mp3?<?php echo time() ?>">Latest Podcast here</a>
```

This would prevent browsers from caching the link as the `href` value would differ everytime.

Comment: The time stamp idea was genius. Perfect. Thank you.